# How to find the expectation of $\sqrt{x}$ and others like it

Tags: probability

Assume a Bernoulli distribution with probability of success $p$. I understand how to find expectations for random variables in general, but how do I go about finding something like $E(\sqrt{x})$ or $E(x^6+1)$? All the examples I have seen refer to finding expectations $E(x)$.

How does the intuition even work for  $E(\sqrt{x})$? In a Bernoulli distribution, we assume a single trial, so how can we have an expectation for this value?

Comment: For a Bernoulli distribution, X=sqrt(X) hence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the expected value of a discrete random variable is $E(X) = \sum_x x\;P(X = x)$. Similarly, for functions $g(X)$ of $X$, we have $E(g(X)) = \sum_x g(x)\;P(X = x)$. Since for a Bernoulli distribution, there are only two possible outcomes $x$, the sum has only two terms: $E(g(X)) = g(0) (1-p) + g(1) p$.

Comment: I see. So basically that means for $E(X^n)$, $E(g(X))=g(0)(1-p)+g(1)p=p$ for any int $n > 0$, right?

Comment: Yup, that's right.